# how would i make a dynamic image?

Tags: php

I have a online.png and a offline.png

My idea is to do serverstatus.php?sid=1

then have it check if the server is online or not, i know how to run the checks for that.
Then have it return the online or offline image with the mime type of png but really a php file and show up like a image. No text or anything added to it. just the original online or offline png. So it can be used for img tags.

Comment: if server is offline you will get 'Server Not Found' Error message

Comment: Yeah. I know. The image runs on a server that checks other servers. So if it gets the 'Server Not Found' Error message' it knows to use the offline.png

Comment: well if the image runs on the server, then you will not be able to get the server (if the server is down), You have to get the image from other server (which is usually online).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PHP documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");

header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [imagecreatefrompng](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) function